# Using for loop to create a dictionary by function

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I managed to use for loop to create a nested function. This is my code:

```
sub="01"
locals()['MSC' + sub] = {}
seeds = ["aHPC", "pHPC", "FPl", "FPm", "ERC", "PHC", "PRC", "46"] 
masks = ["whole", "ERC", "PFl", "FPm"]
hemispheres = ["R", "L"] 
sessions = ["01", "02"] 
for hemi in hemispheres:
    for seed in seeds:
        for mask in masks:
            current_pair = hemi + "_" + seed + "_" + mask
            locals()['MSC' + sub][current_pair] = {}
            for ses in sessions:
                input_dir = "/1D_fc/" + sub + "_" + ses + "/"
                mean_fn = input_dir + "R.Fim." + hemi + "_" + seed + "_" + mask + ".nii.gz"  
                try:
                    mean_brain=nib.load(mean_fn)
                    #control_brain=nib.load(control_fn)
                except:
                    "couldn't load"
                
                mean_data = mean_brain.get_data()  # 3D array; get the dimensions; type(mean_control_data)

                meanDataVector = mean_data.ravel()
                locals()['MSC'+sub][current_pair][ses] = meanDataVector
```

When put all these code into a function, which request for the sub variable as a string. It does not return the nested dictionary as I needed.

```
def CreateDict(sub):
    subject=sub
    locals()['MSC' + sub] = {}
    seeds = ["aHPC", "pHPC", "FPl", "FPm", "ERC", "PHC", "PRC", "46"] 
    masks = ["whole", "ERC", "PFl", "FPm"] 
    hemispheres = ["R", "L"] 
    sessions = ["01", "02"] 
    for hemi in hemispheres:
        for seed in seeds:
            for mask in masks:
                current_pair = hemi + "_" + seed + "_" + mask
                locals()['MSC' + sub][current_pair] = {}
                for ses in sessions:
                    input_dir = "/1D_fc/" + sub + "_" + ses + "/"
                    mean_fn = input_dir + "R.Fim." + hemi + "_" + seed + "_" + mask + ".nii.gz"  
                    try:
                        mean_brain=nib.load(mean_fn)
                        
                    except:
                        "couldn't load"
                    
                    mean_data = mean_brain.get_data()  # 3D array; get the dimensions; type(mean_control_data)
                    
                    meanDataVector = mean_data.ravel()
                    locals()['MSC'+sub][current_pair][ses] = meanDataVector
    return locals()['MSC' + subject]
sub="01"
CreateDict(sub)
```

There is no error message for the function.

Any insight on this? Thanks!

Comment: Using `locals()` here is an abuse of the feature, consider using a dictionary instead.

Comment: The use of `locals()` is a big part of your problem.  Remember that `locals()` in a function is literally local to the function.  Everything in `locals()` evaporates when the function exits, so there will not be an `MSC01` variable.  Just create a local variable in the function and return the local variable.  If the caller wants to store it, the caller will store it.

Comment: Hello Tim, this is very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `locals` like that, just create the dictionary inside your function, `return` it, and assign it to a variable at the call site. Something like this:

```
def create_dict(sub):
    data = {} # no need for locals
    # ...
    return data

msc01 = create_dict('01')
# proceed to use msc01
```

If you want to create and use multiple dictionaries for different `sub` values, consider using another dictionary for that as well:

```
msc = {}
for value in ('01', '02', '03'): 
    msc[value] = create_dict(value)

# now you have msc['01'] etc.
```